# Python object members behaving static, even though they aren't static (that I know of)

Tags: python-3.x, scope, instance, non-static, defaultdict

I have created a class of objects to hold data. Every instance of that class is stored as an item in a dictionary. When I instantiate each instance, using the **init** method from the class, the members, which as set using self.member = ____, are unique, as they should be. However, when I access an instance inside the dictionary later, if I *change* anything in that instance, the change is for some reason applied to *all* the instances stored in the dictionary, which I don't want. For example, if I add to the the `set()` member of `mydict['A']`, as follows:

```
mydict['A'].myset.add('a')
```

then the changes will also appear in mydict['B']. Specifically, if I say:

```
mydict['B'].myset.add('b')
print(mydict['B'].myset)
```

What prints is:

```
{'a', 'b'}
```

despite the fact that I never added `'a'` to `mydict['B']`. The instances, (in the example, mydict['A'] and mydict['B'], but in real life a lot more) were instantiated and printed prior to me trying to change them; before the change, they *appear* to exist independently. All members are defined using self.member = _____, and I've attempted replacing explicit changes to the members, such as

```
mydict['A'].myset.add('b')
```

to methods that will internally change the members, such as

```
def addtoset(self, x):
  self.myset.add(x)
```

but even these attempts did not fix the above problem. Below is a simplified version of all of the code of interest. Thank you in advance for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm a bit new to Python, and this issue has me scratching my head. I'm guessing there's some obscure Python-specific scope rules I'm missing (since Python has an unusual way to handle passing objects into and out of methods), but I've been unable to find a solution.

```
class mydata:
  def __init__(self, myset = set()):
    self.myset = myset
  def addtoset(self, x):
    self.myset.add(x)
class mymethods:
  def update(datadict):
    count = 0
    for md in datadict:
      datadict[md].addtoset(count)
      print(datadict[md].myset)
      count = count+1
if __name__ == '__main__':
  keys = ['A','B','C']
  datadict = defaultdict(mydata)
  for key in keys:
    datadict[key] = mydata()
  mymethods.update(datadict)
```

What prints out for me would be something like:

```
{0}
{0, 1}
{0, 1, 2}
```

despite the fact that I appear to only add one item to each instance's set. What's going on and how can I stop this? (I don't want each instance to have unioned sets). Also note that I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine was able to answer my question. As expected, it is a quirky scope thing. The problem and solution are explained clearly on this link [Python Writing Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Apparently `__init__(self, x=set())` initializes `set()` when the method (in this case, `__init__`) is first created, so every instance of x winds up referencing something like a static instance instead of its own new instance. To fix it you have to initialize *inside* the method. You can default to None and then use a conditional to do this (see link).